# How To Move the selected String in Runtime With The Cursor?

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

I have a little problem and I hope that you have the solution

I work on an Image Editor and I want to draw a text using `Graphics.DrawString` and enable selection of one of them to resize it or move it

[image]

I have another problem:
when I draw it appears under the controls and I want to draw in the most up layer

[image]

Comment: 1): where is the problem? Use Paint event and MouseMove. - issue 2: Sorry. Drawing is always under any child controls.

Comment: That "most up layer" is very hard to come by.  A standard technique is to create a cursor that looks like the text, it is always on top and automatically moves with the mouse.  [Look here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/36028246-7fc8-4cda-a582-de8a675a0827/drag-text-as-image?forum=winforms).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  You've actually asked two questions here.  You may get a more focused response for each if you split separate questions into different posts.